# Select time windows across multiple days from datetime column

Tags: datetime, rows, kdb, q

Given a kdb table with a column of `datetime` type values, is there a simple q query to select all the rows which have their time within a particular window but on any date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
q)t:([]10?.z.z)
q)t
z
-----------------------
2003.06.26T07:32:45.704
2021.09.30T06:05:45.588
2015.08.27T14:41:02.619
2020.12.25T13:06:28.033
2017.05.30T05:15:00.394
2009.02.09T22:27:48.524
2013.07.30T00:10:19.679
2011.01.22T19:25:44.318
2009.01.31T04:21:12.165
2009.12.29T19:41:11.965
q)select from t where z within 06:41 15:32
z
-----------------------
2003.06.26T07:32:45.704
2015.08.27T14:41:02.619
2020.12.25T13:06:28.033
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Could you please explain how it works/what is happening?

Comment: This KX wiki reference explains it well. https://code.kx.com/q/kb/temporal-data/#comparing-temporals

Comment: Essentially when finding times within datetimes, the datetime is converted to time first, rendering the date component redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, explanation and reference. I have marked the answer as accepted, thanks a lot Cathal